# Calculate binomial coefficient in binary

Tags: c, math, numerical-methods, factorial, binomial-coefficients

Is there a fast algorithm for calculating binomial coefficients and leaving the results binary. For example, (10 choose 8) = 101101. I do not need to convert my results to base 10, instead I want to store my results as binary strings. I was asking this question before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You realize of course, that for ordinary integer calculations, the internal representation is binary already.  It's only if/when you use something like `printf("%d")` that an integer gets converted to decimal.

Comment: With that said, there *are* straightforward ways of computing *C(n,k)* that don't involve explicitly calculating *n!* and *k!* and that therefore don't overflow as fast. (If that's what you were worried about.)

Comment: I'm building a binary calculator to output binary to a string. I do not need to work with integers and that's why I asked this question. I wanted to know if there's something like a bit twiddling hack for computing binomial coefficients. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Oh!  Okay.  Sorry if I insulted your intelligence.  (We get questioners on here all the time with the most whimsical ideas of how integer arithmetic works inside.)  I doubt there's a shortcut in binary, though.  Most mathematical algorithms (including the ones I know for combinatorics) just work on numbers, and don't care what base they're in.  So you can write them in terms of `+` and `*` and `!`, or `my_binary_add` and `my_binary_mult` and `my_binary_factorial`, and everything will work out the same in the end.

Comment: What maximum values of the arguments ? (Please don't answer "any".)

Comment: I'm aiming for large coefficients like (1000 choose 500). Thank you for your question.

Comment: Then I am afraid that you have no better options than multiplies and a division.

Comment: Is your goal to work with big numbers, or to work very specifically with individual 0's and 1's?  On the one hand, you're certainly going to need some special code to deal with big numbers, because (1000 choose 500) is a 300-digit, 995-bit number.  But for efficiency's sake, most bignum code works on "chunks", not one bit at a time.  (For example, the bignum code I just tested this example with represents (1000 C 500) as 33 "words" of 31 bits each.)  There's no reason you couldn't represent this number as a data structure with 995 individual bits, and it might be fun, but not too practical.

Comment: Yes, I am working with individual 1s and 0s and I'm not trying to do anything efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the most efficient way. It's performing a prime factorization of the binomial coefficient, then converting to binary. I've added really fast code for finding the prime factorization of a binomial coefficient. It's called [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) and you can use this [online calculator](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/binomial.html) to verify your results. The factorization algorithm is from this [Jstor paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323099). This is a [Haskell](http://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/pr/choose.html) version if you're into that kind of stuff. Note you need to first generate a list of primes on your own. Then test individual primes. Also, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is at work.

```
//Note primeNumber is always less than n
//Inputs n,k,primeNumber 
//Output: e (the exponent of prime number)
//Note: 0 means primeNumber is not a factor of this binomial coefficient
//Example: (n=10,k=3,primeNumber=3), e = 1
//So if you had a list of primes 2,3,5 then for each you get e=3,e=1,e=1. (10,3) = 2^3 *3^1 * 5 ^1 
int BinomialFactorization(int n, int k, int primeNumber)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int exponent = 0;
    int r = 0;
    
    //Finds smaller value between n and n-k since (n choose k) == (n choose n-k)
    //Algorithm only works when k < n/2 
    if(k > (n/2))
    {   
        k = n - k; 
    }
    //Speeds up according to paper
    if(primeNumber > n - k)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //Speeds up according to paper
    if(primeNumber > n/2)
    {
        printf("%d", 0);
        return 0;
    }
    if(primeNumber * primeNumber > n)
    {
        if(n % primeNumber < k % primeNumber)
        {   
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {   //Saw this on online calculator
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //Changing base algorithm 
    while(n > 0)
    {
        a = n % primeNumber;
        n = n / primeNumber;
        b = k % primeNumber + r;
        k = k / primeNumber;
        if(a < b)
        {
            exponent = exponent + 1;
            r = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            r = 0;
        }
    }
    return exponent;    
}
```